# Bind control to specific item in list of observable collections

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a scenario where I have multiple lists of data that is constructed programmatically in a loop.  I want to display these lists side by side on the UI.

I setup a List of ObservableCollections of strings to contain the data.  I am using the ListBox way of binding to the lists as shown here: [Bind textbox list inside listbox in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017906/bind-textbox-list-inside-listbox-in-wpf) 
with this XMAL:

```
<ListBox Name="ListTwo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=obs}" ... >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Name="TextBoxList" Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is how do you bind a specific listbox to an specific index in the List?  Specifically I want the 0th list to bind to List[0], 1st to bind to List[1], etc.

---

So took the below suggestion and tried to make things into a class.  This is what I got, but the UI isn't showing the updates.

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="NS.ClassMainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>

<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="RawBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Foo.Raw}" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="RawItemsTextBoxList" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

DataClass:

```
public class FooClass 
{
    public List<ObservableCollection<string>> items;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Raw { get => this.items[0]; set => this.items[0] = value; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tier1 { get => this.items[1]; set => this.items[1] = value; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tier2 { get => this.items[2]; set => this.items[2] = value; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tier3 { get => this.items[3]; set => this.items[3] = value; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tier4 { get => this.items[4]; set => this.items[4] = value; }

    public FooClass()
    {
        this.items = new List<ObservableCollection<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            this.items.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>());
        }
    }
```

}

And Assignment:

```
this.Foo.Raw = new ObservableCollection<string>(itemNames); // itemNames is a List<string>
```

I am very obviously missing something, but for the life of me can't see it.  Fairly new to WPF so probably is a noob thing.

Comment: I think it would be really helpful if you could provide more context. I find it hard to see a practical need for binding to an observable collection of collections. Usually it is better to structure your data into a hierarchy of data types. Suppose, that instead of a list of strings of strings, which could maybe represent multiple adress books with adresses. You would have a list of types representing the adressbooks, which in turn contain a list of adresses as members. Then your code is best structured as AdressBooksView -> AdressBookView -> Address.

Comment: What is Foo.Raw? Where is the Foo property defined? And what's the DataContext of the ListView/window?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `DataContext` to an instance of a `FooClass` and then set the `Raw` property a non-empty collection like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var foo = new FooClass();
        foo.Raw = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" });
        DataContext = foo;
    }
}
```

...you should see the strings provided that you bind to the `Raw` property and set the `Mode` of the `TextBox` to either `OneTime` or `OneWay`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="RawBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Raw}" 
          Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="RawItemsTextBoxList" Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this override the datacontext set in the window part of the XAML?

Comment: Yes. Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, resetting the DataContext breaks other items in the XMAL that I'm using.

Comment: working now....I had to set the specific datacontext of the ListView and not the window.